# How to implement auth in front-end with Redux?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, redux-saga

I want to know the authentication process on the front end (how and where to save the tokens, how to check if a user is logged in etc), redirect to the login page, when they try to access pages where login is required etc.

I do not want an implementation of this, just libraries to help me, and in case of saving things like tokens, where do I save this?

I am currently learning Redux and have little knowledge, I also saw an article on Saga and it seems to be useful for this authentication process.

As for the back end, I basically need to install some Django extensions and I will have endpoints for things like: enter username / password and return access token, expire an access token, register a user, reset password etc.

For now I know I need Redux and use the Provider and Router of the react-router. Also the basics about actions, reducers, store etc. But nothing more.

Important note: I intend to use hooks instead of class components.

Comment: I'd recommend https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth and this youtube series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aN1LnNq4z54

Comment: React router has a few simple examples in their docs that might give you some ideas: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Answer (score 1):

short explanation:

I recommend you to use JWT for auth, you should save token in localStorage

when you login/signup server response a jwt-token:

```
localStorage.setItem('usertoken', token)
```

and then you should check user auth:

```
const isAuth = localStorage.getItem('usertoken')
```

if you use react-router-4:

```
if (!isAuth) {
  return <Router render={() => <Redirect to="/login" />}
}

// ...your protected routes
```

Also every api request should contain a jwt-token in api.js file:

```
const apiResponse = await fetch(url, {
   ...someOptions,
   headers: { 'x-access-token': localStorage.getItem('usertoken') }
})
```

if server returns 401 response you should delete token:

```
if (response.status === 401) {
    localStorage.removeItem('usertoken');

    window.location.href = '/login';
}
```

An alternative way for auth to use cookies